# Following APIs are greylisted and Google can’t guarantee that they will work on existing versions of Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Before the Launch of app, I got the following warnings, anyone knows how to fix these?

```
API Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
10 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V
2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V
2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z
2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z
2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z
2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;IILandroid/graphics/Typeface;
2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

API Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z
1 occurrence identified
```